# Resource Dictionary DataTemplate does not recognise the x:Name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this `ResourceDictionary` named as `Resource1.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp2">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
        <Button x:Name="SomeButton"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Goal**

I am aiming to add some code code behind without using the ViewModel.

**What I did**

I added a class called `Resource1.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class Resource1
    {

    }
}
```

And the structure now looks like so:

[image]

I have linked the class to the xaml. And also added a click event for the button in the `Resource1.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
                    x:Class="WpfApp2.Resource1">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
        <Button x:Name="SomeButton" Click="SomeButton_Click" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Which then added me an event handler in the `Resource1` class:

```
public partial class Resource1
{
    private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

But when I try getting the `x:Name="SomeButton"` in the class, it does not recognise it..

[image]

**Question**

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do using Resource Dictionary? If so, where do I correct it to make it work?

Comment: Defining data template doesn't add the said button into visual tree. Moreover you can use that button in multiple places (e.g. as item template for `ListBox` items) or in another window (if resource dictionary is merged), which button the name `SomeButton` will then refer? To refer control from templates you need to use more "dynamic" approach (e.g. visual tree lookups), `x:Name` is not the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to generate a member by `x:Name`. Get the Button via the `sender` argument:

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;    
}
```

Be aware that the DataTemplate may be used multiple times, i.e. multiple such Buttons may be created. Which one would you want to reference by the generated member?

Comment: Would this work with other components? Let's say I had a `<TextBlock x:Name="SomeText" />` Within the  `SomeButton_Click` will I be able to pick up the text?

Comment: No (or not easily), as said in the answer, multiple instances of the elements in the DataTemplate might be created.

Comment: Alternative to what? Get the Button as shown in the answer.

Comment: Regarding my first comment to your answer.

Comment: That's a different question, isn't it?

Comment: I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: Ok - the answer you have provided me with is related to my original question. I shall create a new question based on my other comment, unless I find something else on StackOverflow.

Comment: That's why I said it.